# Magento1.9: Not able to send newsletter template to all subscribers

Tags: magento-1.9, template, newsletter

Recently I created a new newsletter template. Then sent it out to all my subscribers. According to newsletter subscribers count, I have `430 subscribers`, but when put in the queue, it only sent out the template to `391 subscribers`.

Could anyone explain what is going on here?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Run the cron and check.

Comment: Explain. I'm new to magento.